# Why is it necessary to list conflicting causes for the emergence Buddhism and Jainism?

Tags: religion, religious-history, buddhism

The emergence of Buddhism and Jainism in 6th Century BC is seen as the result of the following causes (as given in R.S. Sharma's [Ancient India)](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/India_s_Ancient_Past.html?id=VUluAAAAMAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y):

1. Reaction by Kshatriyas
2. The development of new political economy
3. Rise in status of Vaishyas
4. Transforming society

I want to ask is it necessary to see history as a struggle between existing system (thesis) and the coming one (anti-thesis)? All the causes that are given by dialetical theorists for the rise of Buddhism and Jainism seems more like a respect for their Marxist tradition (I cannot avoid the word "Marxist', though I'm not sure if Marx himself ever vowed to see each and every event in history as a struggle) than the actual reasons (if there were reasons at all). New things can happen in this stream of existence, without presence of any anti-thesis, and thus, thesis. Their argument sounds like one of those given in [Caninde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candide) "God gave us a nose for spectacles to rest on".

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)  Thesis/antithesis/synthesis is only necessary if you're using dialectical tools. Have you looked at alternate theories of history?  physiocrats? Big Man? Whig?   Your question seems to be a challenge to dialectal materialism, but your title about theological changes. Which question do you want answered?

Comment: @MCW My question is about the application of Dialectical materialistic theory of history to this particular scenario.

Comment: The only question I see in the body seems to be a subjective "headline"-style question, begging for an application of [Betteridge's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betteridge%27s_law_of_headlines). Also, it would be nice if this could be edited to harmonize the "Why" question in the title with the yes/no question in the body.

Comment: @ConGovDeIn, OP replying in comments is an anti-pattern that is associated with question closure.  Best practice is to update the question to address the issues raised in comments and then flag the comment for deletion.  If your question is about dialectical materialism in history, I'd recommend removing mention of Jainism and Buddhism from the title. You're more likely to attract attention from people who research that topic and are best able to give you a satisfactory answer.    Clarity of question is key to satisfactory answer.

Comment: I admit I'm confused as to what the question is here. Are you trying to argue that there is one single reason so that there can't be a list of reason?